# Can an example be mentioned like this

Tags: sentence-construction, definite-article

> As an example of the role of context in classification of a node, suppose a user wants to remove the navigation links in the sidebar section. To accomplish this task, they may define a rule to eliminate parts of the page that have high link density.

Can an example be mentioned like this? besides, I don't know if I should say *parts of page*, *the parts of the page*, *parts of the page*....

Comment: *Grammatically,* all your alternatives are fine. *Stylistically,* I would probably go for ***those** parts of the page* (or *of **a** page*, but it's really nit-picking to argue for any specific usage).

Comment: "*As an example* ... *suppose* ..." - I don't think it chimes.  I'd probably say, "*To understand* the role of context ..., *suppose*".

Comment: @VictorBazarov then maybe "*To demonstrate* the role of ..."

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.  Since it's you who *demonstrates*, perhaps then you could add "*let us*" before *suppose*.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I would use

> eliminate parts of **a** page

if the links can be eliminated on ***any*** page, since it's a navigation bar, it probably occurs on every page.

Otherwise

> eliminate parts of **the** page

would refer to a particular page, like the landing page.

Comment: I would add that "the" should be used also in front of "parts" since you have mentioned the specific parts of the page in the previous sentence.